# How to insert the date gap when rbind 2 dataframes with discontinuous date (POSIXct) in r?

Tags: r, nan, posixct, rbind

My 2 dataframes look like this:

```
dput(SB6)
structure(list(shf_htr_resstnc_SB1_1 = c(99.7, 99.7, 99.7, 99.7, 
99.7), shfp_wrnng_SB1_1_1_1_1 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN), rDate = structure(c(1650988800, 
1650990600, 1650992400, 1650994200, 1650996000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = 7566:7570, class = "data.frame")
```

```
dput(SB6.1)
structure(list(shf_htr_resstnc_SB1_1 = c(99.7, 99.7, 99.7, 99.7, 
99.7), shfp_wrnng_SB1_1_1_1_1 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN), rDate = structure(c(1651620600, 
1651622400, 1651624200, 1651626000, 1651627800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = 5:9, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to `rbind` both dataframes and insert the time gap between them. **SB6** finish on *2022-04-26 18:00:00* and **SB6.1** starts at *2022-05-03 22:30:00*. Note that the time stamp is 30 in 30 minutes. Between this time gap, the variables should be filled with `NaN`.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could bind the datasets and use `complete` on the `seq`uence from `min` to `max` of 'rDate by` an interval of '30 min'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(SB6, SB6.1) %>%
   complete(rDate = seq(min(rDate), max(rDate), by = "30 min"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `full_seq()` from `tidyr` to create the full sequence of datetimes.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(SB6, SB6.1) %>%
  complete(rDate = full_seq(rDate, period = 60*30))
```